# JS find bad font-family in list of options in select option tags. (fonts: Wingdings..)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fonts, html-select

My select tag is populated with all  the fonts in my computer.
Each option in the Select should show as different font style.
Using Chrome browser, they will somtimes fail to show in their
different fonts.

[image]

In the snippets below I've entered 2 lists.
The first is the broken one, and second works fine.
The difference was when I removed 2 option tags (287, 288)
They had font families: 'Wingdings 2' and 'Wingdings 3'.

My question is how to detect these kinds of 'bug?' fonts that
will break the fuction of my fonts list.

PS. Stackoverflow.com will not let me enter more than 30000 chars
so I cut off around half off the second list

```html
<span> Bad list-></span>
<select id="fontList" name="fontList">
  <option style="font-family: 'Agency FB'">Agency FB</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Aharoni'">Aharoni</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Alef'">Alef</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Algerian'">Algerian</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Andalus'">Andalus</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Angsana New'">Angsana New</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'AngsanaUPC'">AngsanaUPC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Aparajita'">Aparajita</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Arabic Typesetting'">Arabic Typesetting</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Arial'">Arial</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Arial Black'">Arial Black</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Arial Narrow'">Arial Narrow</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'">Arial Unicode MS</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Baskerville Old Face'">Baskerville Old Face</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Batang'">Batang</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'BatangChe'">BatangChe</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bauhaus 93'">Bauhaus 93</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bell MT'">Bell MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Berlin Sans FB'">Berlin Sans FB</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bernard MT Condensed'">Bernard MT Condensed</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Blackadder ITC'">Blackadder ITC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bodoni Bd BT'">Bodoni Bd BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bodoni Bk BT'">Bodoni Bk BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bodoni MT'">Bodoni MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bodoni MT Black'">Bodoni MT Black</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bodoni MT Condensed'">Bodoni MT Condensed</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Book Antiqua'">Book Antiqua</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bookman Old Style'">Bookman Old Style</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bookshelf Symbol 7'">Bookshelf Symbol 7</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Bradley Hand ITC'">Bradley Hand ITC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Broadway'">Broadway</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Browallia New'">Browallia New</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'BrowalliaUPC'">BrowalliaUPC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Brush Script MT'">Brush Script MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Calibri'">Calibri</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Calibri Light'">Calibri Light</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Californian FB'">Californian FB</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Calisto MT'">Calisto MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Cambria'">Cambria</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Cambria Math'">Cambria Math</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Candara'">Candara</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Castellar'">Castellar</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Centaur'">Centaur</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'CentSchbkCyrill BT'">CentSchbkCyrill BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Century'">Century</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Century Gothic'">Century Gothic</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Century Schoolbook'">Century Schoolbook</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Century725 Cn BT'">Century725 Cn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Century751 BT'">Century751 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Century751 No2 BT'">Century751 No2 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Century751 SeBd BT'">Century751 SeBd BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Chapenettoer 8 THIN'">Chapenettoer 8 THIN</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Chiller'">Chiller</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Clarendon Blk BT'">Clarendon Blk BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Clarendon BT'">Clarendon BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Clarendon Lt BT'">Clarendon Lt BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Colonna MT'">Colonna MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'">Comic Sans MS</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Consolas'">Consolas</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Constantia'">Constantia</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Cooper Black'">Cooper Black</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Copperplate Gothic Light'">Copperplate Gothic Light</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Corbel'">Corbel</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Cordia New'">Cordia New</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'CordiaUPC'">CordiaUPC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Courier'">Courier</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Courier New'">Courier New</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Curlz MT'">Curlz MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'DaunPenh'">DaunPenh</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'DeVinne Txt BT'">DeVinne Txt BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'DFGothic-EB'">DFGothic-EB</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'DFKai-SB'">DFKai-SB</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'DFMincho-SU'">DFMincho-SU</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'DFMincho-UB'">DFMincho-UB</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'DFPOP1-W9'">DFPOP1-W9</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'DilleniaUPC'">DilleniaUPC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'DokChampa'">DokChampa</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Dotum'">Dotum</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'DotumChe'">DotumChe</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Ebrima'">Ebrima</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Edwardian Script ITC'">Edwardian Script ITC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Elephant'">Elephant</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Embassy BT'">Embassy BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Engravers MT'">Engravers MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'EngraversGothic BT'">EngraversGothic BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Estrangelo Edessa'">Estrangelo Edessa</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'EucrosiaUPC'">EucrosiaUPC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Euphemia'">Euphemia</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Exotc350 Bd BT'">Exotc350 Bd BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Exotc350 DmBd BT'">Exotc350 DmBd BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'FangSong'">FangSong</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Felix Titling'">Felix Titling</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01'">Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Footlight MT Light'">Footlight MT Light</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Forte'">Forte</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Book'">Franklin Gothic Book</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Heavy'">Franklin Gothic Heavy</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium'">Franklin Gothic Medium</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Freehand521 BT'">Freehand521 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'FreesiaUPC'">FreesiaUPC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Freestyle Script'">Freestyle Script</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'French Script MT'">French Script MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Futura Bk BT'">Futura Bk BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Futura Md BT'">Futura Md BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Gabriola'">Gabriola</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Garamond'">Garamond</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Gautami'">Gautami</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Geometr212 BkCn BT'">Geometr212 BkCn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Geometr415 Blk BT'">Geometr415 Blk BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Geometr706 BlkCn BT'">Geometr706 BlkCn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Georgia'">Georgia</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'GeoSlab703 Md BT'">GeoSlab703 Md BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'GeoSlab703 MdCn BT'">GeoSlab703 MdCn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Gigi'">Gigi</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Gill Sans MT'">Gill Sans MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Gill Sans MT Condensed'">Gill Sans MT Condensed</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Gisha'">Gisha</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Goudy Old Style'">Goudy Old Style</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Goudy Stout'">Goudy Stout</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Gulim'">Gulim</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'GulimChe'">GulimChe</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Gungsuh'">Gungsuh</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'GungsuhChe'">GungsuhChe</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Guttman Logo1'">Guttman Logo1</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Haettenschweiler'">Haettenschweiler</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Harrington'">Harrington</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'High Tower Text'">High Tower Text</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Humanst521 BT'">Humanst521 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Humanst521 Lt BT'">Humanst521 Lt BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Humnst777 Blk BT'">Humnst777 Blk BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Humnst777 BlkCn BT'">Humnst777 BlkCn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Humnst777 BT'">Humnst777 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Humnst777 Cn BT'">Humnst777 Cn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Humnst777 Lt BT'">Humnst777 Lt BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Impact'">Impact</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Imprint MT Shadow'">Imprint MT Shadow</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Informal Roman'">Informal Roman</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'IrisUPC'">IrisUPC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Japanese'">Japanese</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'JasmineUPC'">JasmineUPC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Jokerman'">Jokerman</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Juice ITC'">Juice ITC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'KaiTi'">KaiTi</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Kalinga'">Kalinga</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Kartika'">Kartika</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Kaufmann BT'">Kaufmann BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Khmer UI'">Khmer UI</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'KodchiangUPC'">KodchiangUPC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Kokila'">Kokila</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Kristen ITC'">Kristen ITC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Kunstler Script'">Kunstler Script</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Lao UI'">Lao UI</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Latha'">Latha</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Leelawadee'">Leelawadee</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Levenim MT'">Levenim MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'LilyUPC'">LilyUPC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Liron'">Liron</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Lithos Pro Light'">Lithos Pro Light</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Lucida Bright'">Lucida Bright</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Lucida Calligraphy'">Lucida Calligraphy</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Lucida Console'">Lucida Console</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Lucida Fax'">Lucida Fax</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Lucida Handwriting'">Lucida Handwriting</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Lucida Sans'">Lucida Sans</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Lucida Sans Typewriter'">Lucida Sans Typewriter</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode'">Lucida Sans Unicode</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'LuzSans-Book'">LuzSans-Book</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Magneto'">Magneto</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Maiandra GD'">Maiandra GD</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Malgun Gothic'">Malgun Gothic</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Mangal'">Mangal</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Matura MT Script Capitals'">Matura MT Script Capitals</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Meiryo'">Meiryo</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Meiryo UI'">Meiryo UI</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Microsoft Himalaya'">Microsoft Himalaya</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Microsoft JhengHei'">Microsoft JhengHei</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Microsoft New Tai Lue'">Microsoft New Tai Lue</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Microsoft PhagsPa'">Microsoft PhagsPa</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Microsoft Sans Serif'">Microsoft Sans Serif</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Microsoft Tai Le'">Microsoft Tai Le</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Microsoft Uighur'">Microsoft Uighur</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Microsoft YaHei'">Microsoft YaHei</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Microsoft Yi Baiti'">Microsoft Yi Baiti</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MingLiU'">MingLiU</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MingLiU-ExtB'">MingLiU-ExtB</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MingLiU_HKSCS'">MingLiU_HKSCS</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB'">MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Miriam'">Miriam</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Miriam Fixed'">Miriam Fixed</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Mistral'">Mistral</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Modern No. 20'">Modern No. 20</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Monotype Corsiva'">Monotype Corsiva</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Monotype Hadassah'">Monotype Hadassah</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MoolBoran'">MoolBoran</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MS Gothic'">MS Gothic</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MS Mincho'">MS Mincho</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MS PGothic'">MS PGothic</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MS PMincho'">MS PMincho</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MS Reference Sans Serif'">MS Reference Sans Serif</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MS Reference Specialty'">MS Reference Specialty</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MS Sans Serif'">MS Sans Serif</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MS UI Gothic'">MS UI Gothic</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'MV Boli'">MV Boli</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Myriad Pro'">Myriad Pro</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Myriad Pro Light'">Myriad Pro Light</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Narkisim'">Narkisim</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'News701 BT'">News701 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'News706 BT'">News706 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'NewsGoth BT'">NewsGoth BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'NewsGoth Cn BT'">NewsGoth Cn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'NewsGoth Lt BT'">NewsGoth Lt BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Niagara Engraved'">Niagara Engraved</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Niagara Solid'">Niagara Solid</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'NSimSun'">NSimSun</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Nyala'">Nyala</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'OCR-A BT'">OCR-A BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'OCR-B 10 BT'">OCR-B 10 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Old English Text MT'">Old English Text MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Onyx'">Onyx</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Palace Script MT'">Palace Script MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Palatino Linotype'">Palatino Linotype</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Papyrus'">Papyrus</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Parchment'">Parchment</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Perpetua'">Perpetua</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Perpetua Titling MT'">Perpetua Titling MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Plantagenet Cherokee'">Plantagenet Cherokee</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Playbill'">Playbill</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'PMingLiU'">PMingLiU</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'PMingLiU-ExtB'">PMingLiU-ExtB</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Poor Richard'">Poor Richard</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Pristina'">Pristina</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Raavi'">Raavi</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Ravie'">Ravie</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Rockwell'">Rockwell</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Rockwell Condensed'">Rockwell Condensed</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Rod'">Rod</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Sakkal Majalla'">Sakkal Majalla</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Schadow BT'">Schadow BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Segoe Print'">Segoe Print</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Segoe Script'">Segoe Script</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'">Segoe UI</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Light'">Segoe UI Light</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Semibold'">Segoe UI Semibold</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Segoe UI Symbol'">Segoe UI Symbol</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Shonar Bangla'">Shonar Bangla</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Showcard Gothic'">Showcard Gothic</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Shruti'">Shruti</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'SimHei'">SimHei</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Simplified Arabic'">Simplified Arabic</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Simplified Arabic Fixed'">Simplified Arabic Fixed</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'SimSun'">SimSun</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'SimSun-ExtB'">SimSun-ExtB</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Snap ITC'">Snap ITC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Square721 BT'">Square721 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Square721 Cn BT'">Square721 Cn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Stencil'">Stencil</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Swis721 Blk BT'">Swis721 Blk BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Swis721 BlkCn BT'">Swis721 BlkCn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Swis721 BT'">Swis721 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Swis721 Cn BT'">Swis721 Cn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Swis721 Hv BT'">Swis721 Hv BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Swis721 Lt BT'">Swis721 Lt BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Swis721 LtEx BT'">Swis721 LtEx BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Swis721 WGL4 BT'">Swis721 WGL4 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Sylfaen'">Sylfaen</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Symbol'">Symbol</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Tahoma'">Tahoma</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Tamir'">Tamir</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Tempus Sans ITC'">Tempus Sans ITC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'">Times New Roman</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Traditional Arabic'">Traditional Arabic</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS'">Trebuchet MS</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Tunga'">Tunga</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Tw Cen MT'">Tw Cen MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Tw Cen MT Condensed'">Tw Cen MT Condensed</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'TypoUpright BT'">TypoUpright BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Utsaah'">Utsaah</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Vani'">Vani</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Verdana'">Verdana</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Vijaya'">Vijaya</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Viner Hand ITC'">Viner Hand ITC</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Vivaldi'">Vivaldi</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Vladimir Script'">Vladimir Script</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Vrinda'">Vrinda</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Webdings'">Webdings</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Wide Latin'">Wide Latin</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Wingdings'">Wingdings</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Wingdings 2'">Wingdings 2</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'Wingdings 3'">Wingdings 3</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP Arabic Sihafa'">WP Arabic Sihafa</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP ArabicScript Sihafa'">WP ArabicScript Sihafa</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP CyrillicA'">WP CyrillicA</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP Greek Century'">WP Greek Century</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP Greek Courier'">WP Greek Courier</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP Greek Helve'">WP Greek Helve</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP Hebrew David'">WP Hebrew David</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP MultinationalA Courier'">WP MultinationalA Courier</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP MultinationalA Helve'">WP MultinationalA Helve</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP MultinationalA Roman'">WP MultinationalA Roman</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'WP MultinationalB Courier'">WP MultinationalB Courier</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'ＤＦ中太楷書体'">ＤＦ中太楷書体</option>
  <option style="font-family: 'ＤＦ明朝体W5'">ＤＦ明朝体W5</option>
</select>

<span> Good list-></span>

<select id="fontList">
  <option style="font-family: Agency FB">Agency FB</option>
  <option style="font-family: Aharoni">Aharoni</option>
  <option style="font-family: Myriad Pro Light">Myriad Pro Light</option>
  <option style="font-family: Narkisim">Narkisim</option>
  <option style="font-family: News701 BT">News701 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: News706 BT">News706 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: NewsGoth BT">NewsGoth BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: NewsGoth Cn BT">NewsGoth Cn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: NewsGoth Lt BT">NewsGoth Lt BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Niagara Engraved">Niagara Engraved</option>
  <option style="font-family: Niagara Solid">Niagara Solid</option>
  <option style="font-family: NSimSun">NSimSun</option>
  <option style="font-family: Nyala">Nyala</option>
  <option style="font-family: OCR-A BT">OCR-A BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: OCR-B 10 BT">OCR-B 10 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Old English Text MT">Old English Text MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Onyx">Onyx</option>
  <option style="font-family: Palace Script MT">Palace Script MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Palatino Linotype">Palatino Linotype</option>
  <option style="font-family: Papyrus">Papyrus</option>
  <option style="font-family: Parchment">Parchment</option>
  <option style="font-family: Perpetua">Perpetua</option>
  <option style="font-family: Perpetua Titling MT">Perpetua Titling MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Plantagenet Cherokee">Plantagenet Cherokee</option>
  <option style="font-family: Playbill">Playbill</option>
  <option style="font-family: PMingLiU">PMingLiU</option>
  <option style="font-family: PMingLiU-ExtB">PMingLiU-ExtB</option>
  <option style="font-family: Poor Richard">Poor Richard</option>
  <option style="font-family: Pristina">Pristina</option>
  <option style="font-family: Raavi">Raavi</option>
  <option style="font-family: Ravie">Ravie</option>
  <option style="font-family: Rockwell">Rockwell</option>
  <option style="font-family: Rockwell Condensed">Rockwell Condensed</option>
  <option style="font-family: Rod">Rod</option>
  <option style="font-family: Sakkal Majalla">Sakkal Majalla</option>
  <option style="font-family: Schadow BT">Schadow BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Segoe Print">Segoe Print</option>
  <option style="font-family: Segoe Script">Segoe Script</option>
  <option style="font-family: Segoe UI">Segoe UI</option>
  <option style="font-family: Segoe UI Light">Segoe UI Light</option>
  <option style="font-family: Segoe UI Semibold">Segoe UI Semibold</option>
  <option style="font-family: Segoe UI Symbol">Segoe UI Symbol</option>
  <option style="font-family: Shonar Bangla">Shonar Bangla</option>
  <option style="font-family: Showcard Gothic">Showcard Gothic</option>
  <option style="font-family: Shruti">Shruti</option>
  <option style="font-family: Swis721 BT">Swis721 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Swis721 Cn BT">Swis721 Cn BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Swis721 Hv BT">Swis721 Hv BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Swis721 Lt BT">Swis721 Lt BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Swis721 LtEx BT">Swis721 LtEx BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Swis721 WGL4 BT">Swis721 WGL4 BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Sylfaen">Sylfaen</option>
  <option style="font-family: Symbol">Symbol</option>
  <option style="font-family: Tahoma">Tahoma</option>
  <option style="font-family: Tamir">Tamir</option>
  <option style="font-family: Tempus Sans ITC">Tempus Sans ITC</option>
  <option style="font-family: Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option>
  <option style="font-family: Traditional Arabic">Traditional Arabic</option>
  <option style="font-family: Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option>
  <option style="font-family: Tunga">Tunga</option>
  <option style="font-family: Tw Cen MT">Tw Cen MT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Tw Cen MT Condensed">Tw Cen MT Condensed</option>
  <option style="font-family: TypoUpright BT">TypoUpright BT</option>
  <option style="font-family: Utsaah">Utsaah</option>
  <option style="font-family: Vani">Vani</option>
  <option style="font-family: Verdana">Verdana</option>
  <option style="font-family: Vijaya">Vijaya</option>
  <option style="font-family: Viner Hand ITC">Viner Hand ITC</option>
  <option style="font-family: Vivaldi">Vivaldi</option>
  <option style="font-family: Vladimir Script">Vladimir Script</option>
  <option style="font-family: Vrinda">Vrinda</option>
  <option style="font-family: Webdings">Webdings</option>
  <option style="font-family: Wide Latin">Wide Latin</option>
  <option style="font-family: Wingdings">Wingdings</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP Arabic Sihafa">WP Arabic Sihafa</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP ArabicScript Sihafa">WP ArabicScript Sihafa</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP CyrillicA">WP CyrillicA</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP Greek Century">WP Greek Century</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP Greek Courier">WP Greek Courier</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP Greek Helve">WP Greek Helve</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP Hebrew David">WP Hebrew David</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP MultinationalA Courier">WP MultinationalA Courier</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP MultinationalA Helve">WP MultinationalA Helve</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP MultinationalA Roman">WP MultinationalA Roman</option>
  <option style="font-family: WP MultinationalB Courier">WP MultinationalB Courier</option>
  <option style="font-family: ＤＦ中太楷書体">ＤＦ中太楷書体</option>
  <option style="font-family: ＤＦ明朝体W5">ＤＦ明朝体W5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not have read up on the correct use of the `font-family` property. Read over [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-family) and pay special attention to the section that explains when font names **must** be quoted strings.

All those families with spaces, for instance, need to be quoted. Right now, all of those are illegal values.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Mike. But the problem persists. I have added the quotes in the snippet to the bad list. It is still bad.

Comment: only family names with special characters need quotes, so "batang" doesn't need them, for instance. That said: reduce your test case. Don't list a hundred fonts, find three and have a look at where things go wrong, because that makes it much easier to figure out what's going on.